# Flutter: Why app doesn't start listen for stream only if I run with hot restart?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, streaming

I'm new to flutter and trying to build application to get user's speed and listen to it using streams with Geolocator plugin but, the thing is when the user accepts accessing to their location, the app doesn't start listening for his location but if I press hot restart it work perfect. I've tried using async function in initState and used setState function but nothing works .. please could anyone help me with this I've been struggling for days

This's my piece of code:

```
import 'package:my_testing/Components/constants.dart';
import 'package:my_testing/Screens/setting_screen.dart';
import 'package:my_testing/Services/weather.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:my_testing/Services/user_location.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_gauges/gauges.dart';
import 'package:flutter_glow/flutter_glow.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:my_testing/Services/road_map.dart';
import 'dart:async';

///1- this class is for the main screen:
class SpeedScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _SpeedScreenState createState() => _SpeedScreenState ();
}

class _SpeedScreenState extends State<SpeedScreen>{

  StreamController<double> speedController = StreamController<double>.broadcast();
  Stream<double> get speedStream => speedController.stream;
  StreamSubscription<Position>? streamSubscription1;
  double randomNumber = 240.0; 
  String? speedUnit = 'MPH';
  double? speedInMPH;


  void detectFastSpeedWithAlert(double? userSpeed) {
    double fastSpeed = 50.0;

    while (userSpeed! >= fastSpeed && SettingDrawer.isSwitched == true) {
      SettingDrawer.playAlertSound();
      break;
    }
    SettingDrawer.stopAlertSound();
  }

  void getSpeedInMPH() { ///HERE IS MY PROBLEM (p-1) //TODO:
    speedInMPH= 0.0;
   // Geolocator.requestPermission().then((value) {
      //if (value== LocationPermission.always || value == LocationPermission.whileInUse){
        Geolocator.getPositionStream(
            intervalDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000), 
            desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation).listen((position) { 
          speedController.add(speedInMPH!);
          setState(() {
            speedInMPH = position.speed * (2.23693629); 
            print('the Speed Stream are $speedInMPH'); 
          });
          detectFastSpeedWithAlert(speedInMPH);
            });
  }

  @override
  void initState() { ///ALSO HERE IS MY PROBLEM (p-2) //TODO:
    super.initState();
    speedInMPH=0.0;
    getSpeedInMPH();
  
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    streamSubscription1?.cancel();
  }

  ///this function for passing the lat and long to RoadMap
  void passingLatLongData() async {

    UserLocation loc= UserLocation();
    await loc.getUserLocation();
    var roadLat= loc.lat;
    var roadLong= loc.long;

    Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context){
          return RoadMap(
            userLat: roadLat, 
            userLong: roadLong,
          );
        }),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<double>(
      create: (_)=> speedStream, //in new version of StreamProvider, use create instead of builder
      initialData: 0.0,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 0.0,
            centerTitle: true, 
            title: Text('  MY TESTING APP',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 15.0,
                color: Color(0xFF868DB4),
              ),
            ),
            leading: Builder(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    FontAwesomeIcons.cogs,
                    size: 30.0,
                    color: kIconColor,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          body: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 20.0),
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 3,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: (){
                        print('Gauge has been pressed'); 
                      },
                      child: Stack(children: [
                        Positioned(
                          height: 320.0,
                          left: 0,
                          right: 0,
                          bottom: -15.0,
                          child: SfRadialGauge(
                            enableLoadingAnimation: true,
                            animationDuration: 2000,
                            axes: <RadialAxis>[
                              RadialAxis(minimum: 0,maximum: 240,
                                showLabels: false,
                                showTicks: true, 
                                radiusFactor: 0.70,
                                axisLineStyle: AxisLineStyle(
                                  cornerStyle: CornerStyle.bothCurve,
                                  color: Color(0x363F467E),
                                  thickness: 13.5,
                                ),
                                majorTickStyle: MajorTickStyle(
                                  length: 1,
                                  thickness: 0.0,
                                  color: kTextColor,
                                ),
                                annotations: <GaugeAnnotation>[
                                  GaugeAnnotation(
                                    widget: GlowText('${speedInMPH!.toInt()}',
                                      glowColor: kGaugeColor,
                                      blurRadius: 15.0,
                                      offset: Offset(0.0,0.0),
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 28.0,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                        color: Colors.tealAccent.shade100,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    positionFactor: 0.9,
                                    angle: 102,
                                  ),
                                  GaugeAnnotation(
                                    widget: Text(' $speedUnit', 
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 15.0,
                                        color: kTextColor,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    positionFactor: 0.98,
                                    angle: 70.0,
                                  ),
                                ],
                                pointers: [
                                  RangePointer(
                                    animationType: AnimationType.elasticOut,
                                    value: randomNumber,
                                    animationDuration: 2000,
                                    enableAnimation: true,
                                    width: 13.5,
                                    cornerStyle: CornerStyle.bothCurve,
                                    color: kGaugeColor,
                                  ),
                                  NeedlePointer(
                                    animationType: AnimationType.elasticOut,
                                    value: speedInMPH!.roundToDouble(),
                                    animationDuration: 2000,
                                    enableAnimation: true,
                                    needleColor: kGaugeColor,
                                    needleStartWidth: 0.6,
                                    needleEndWidth: 8.0,
                                    knobStyle: KnobStyle(
                                      knobRadius: 0.07,
                                      color: kGaugeColor,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                              
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),),
                      ]),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: Weather(),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 5.0,
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: myContainerButton( 
                              containerIcon: FontAwesomeIcons.locationArrow,
                              containerOnPressed: () {
                                passingLatLongData();
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ]),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5.0,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: myContainerButton(
                      containerIcon: Icons.error_outline, 
                      containerText: 'Information',
                    ),
                  ),
                ]
            ),
          ),
          drawer: SettingDrawer(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget myContainerButton({@required IconData? containerIcon,String? containerText, Function()? containerOnPressed}){

  return Container(
    child: TextButton(
      onPressed: containerOnPressed, 
      child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 9.0, vertical: 7.0),
              child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                      containerIcon,
                      color: kIconColor,
                      size: 30.0,
                      //or Color(0xFF7179B9),
                    ),
                    Text('  $containerText',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: kTextColor,
                        fontSize: 12.0,
                      
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]
              ),
            ),
          ]
      ),
    ),
    decoration: kBoxDecoration,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `initState()` is called only once, when widget is inserted into the `widget-tree` as shown in [official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html). and since you are hot reloading `initState()` will not called.

update:-

you can actually use `didUpdateWidget()` for hot reload to work

```
@override
  void didUpdateWidget(oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    //your code for stream
  }
```

Comment: So i called my function that operate the stream in the initState .. doesn’t that mean it should start streaming once the widget is inserted in the widget tree? Or what should I do to fix this ? I’m sorry I’m a beginner to that

Comment: updated the answer @Rash

Comment: Thank you sir, I solved the problem by switching to StreamBuilder instead of StreamProvider, it turns out that I don't have enough knowledge in it.. But your solution did solve another problem.. really appreciate your help sir